# How to read the code off of an ESP8285?

Tags: microcontroller

I was using an ESP8285 for a project that I started a little bit ago. I had let the project sit for awhile and had lost the documentation including the source code. Is there a way to pull the code out like as a hex file and upload it to a new ESP8285 module that I have?

Comment: You might be able to "clone" it, but the source code is gone, so you'll never be able to finish the project.   Check carefully for misplaced files, otherwise you should probably start again; having a sense of the right path from your past experience will make that more efficient than the first time around.

Comment: Would esptool be able to do something like this?

Comment: Well, I usually document my code for later reference. Last time I learned ESP8266-12 to blink LED, I actually wrote 150+ posts (Ref 2 below). But almost always I don't use old code, because new ESP models and new IDEs and libraries coming out every quarter. Now I have just bought ESP32 and looking for new IDEs. ESP8266 is indeed to get started, so you might to like read this ESP8255 instructable to refresh your mind: (1) ESP8285 Instructable - How to Get Started (& Blink a LED)? - Projectsforallr: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Get-Started-With-ESP8285-Module-/  to continue, ...

Comment: The above tutorial is a bit brief. If you wish to know more detials on how me esp8266 newbie learn ESP8266, you might like to skim my 150 posts long learning log to refresh your memory. I also got started with writing a blink LED program which took me a couple of weeks. Yes ALL the IDEs (I spent many hours evaluating them)  are difficult and the learning curve is very steep, unless you learn the easy way, using baby micro python. If you are using NodeMCU, there is a comprehensive library for sensors etc. So if you are using NodeMCU, and sensor you are using, perhaps I can brainstorm ideas.

Comment: And this is my ESP8266 leaning log: (2) ESP8266 Learning Notes (150+ posts) - tlfong01, rpi.org.forum, 2018sep
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&p=1368181&hilit=esp8266+tlfong01#p1368181. Happy ESP8266 Programming. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for your loss. Learn from this unfortunate experience by adding git to your skill set. All Code is Temporary - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/251029/110633

Comment: @MarkUm, Many thanks for your pro advice on using Git. I skimmed all the answers in  your GIT Q&A link and I think it should be very good for software engineers or would be software engineers. But me hobbyist programmer messing with Rpi pyhton Micky Mouse ENC/EE/SE projects do have huge difficulties going the GIT way. Ah, lunch time, I will carry on this afternoon, ...

Comment: @tlfong01 Lots of good material in your comments - it would be appreciated if you can turn them into an answer - even not much more than copy and paste would be more useful than leaving the material in comments, which are often transient.

Comment: @Russell McMahon, thank you for your suggestion. I never thought that comments are transient, I wrongly thought that they stayed forever. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 Comment lifetime is variable. A moderator may move all comments to chat if there become too many - as happens. And for whatever reason some are deleted. I lean towards retaining them in all except special cases. (Rude, irrelevant, spam , ...) Also, people searching answers fora problem are liable to skip over comments - or just look at answers per se. Overall the way the site is designed makes answers more accessible and more permanent.

Comment: @Russell McMahon, Ah I totally agree with what you said that answers are more accessible and more permanent. But quick answers without a thorough understanding of the question and the OP's knowledge and skills might not be useful to the future readers. You remind me a recent SO blog which says more or less the following couple of points: (1) A newbie often doesn't know what he doesn't know, and so (2) It might be a good idea to guide the newbie to an question and then give the answer that newbie really wants, / to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Q&A type of forums like SO and SE often have questions and answers scattered here and there, with no particular time order, in different answering styles, using different technical and terms, and even if the Q&A system can use tags to group the relative and relevant answers, the newbie may not be knowledgeable enough to pick the answers that suits to help him to solve his problem. There are other problems including the following: (4) Many questions and answer related to fast changing hardware versions gets outdated soon. / to continue, ...

Comment: Everybody was excited to learn, but there are too many teething problems, so newbies had a difficult time learning, and latter ESP8266 came, and became a milestone, then things got settled down a bit, but then no good IDEs were available for newbies. So the learning curve for newbies was very steep. Often the vendor only caters the professionals and don't bother to be considerate to the newbies. So I actually spent some 200 hours learning ESP8266-12 but concluded that the architecture and ecosystem is not yet ready for newbies. / to continue, ...

Comment: My ESP8266-12 project actually stalled for two years and now the time has come that the IDE for ESP32 are getting mature, hardware price drops to an affordable level, everybody does not find not so scary for the faint of heart newbies, then perhaps I can resume my learning. There are other complications, say ESP8266 is very good for WiFi app, and NoeMCU using LUA is very good for event driven  programs for gaming apps. / to continue, ...

Comment: But event driven programming using LUA again is very difficult to get started, except for the gaming programmers.,  ...  I am just thinking aloud, my apologies for the typo errors. Ah, supper time, so see you tomorrow, / to continue,